# Is It possible to add my application in account?

Tags: android

I am trying to add my application in account same as Gmail and whatsapp do.I did lots of search but no luck.

I want something like this:
[image: I want something like this.]

Comment: this might help you https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow isn't a place where you just ask how is something done and expect to get an answer. You have to show what you've tried and what isn't working.

As for your question, applications only appear in the account list if the application is performing some sort of data synchronisation between the app and a server. Therefore you would need to create a sync adapter.

Below are two links that show how to do this

[Android Dev Guide - Creating a Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

[Tutorial for creating your own sync adapter](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/)

Hope this helps